# Define vector input for dymos ODE?

Tags: openmdao

For all dymos examples that I've seen (for example, this [brachistochrone](https://openmdao.github.io/dymos/examples/brachistochrone/brachistochrone.html)), the inputs are defined as follows:

```
self.add_input('name', val=np.ones(num_nodes), ...)
```

where `num_nodes` is number of nodes in the transcription scheme. Instead, can I do something like below?

```
self.add_input('name', val=np.ones(num_nodes, node), ...)
```

For example, a use case for this scenario will be I have a displacement variable that has 3 components (x, y, z), and I don't want to repeat myself by calling  `self.add_input(...)` three times.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can define the state as

`self.add_input('name', shape=(num_nodes, state_size), ...)`

See this version of the [brachistochrone problem](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/blob/master/dymos/examples/brachistochrone/brachistochrone_vector_states_ode.py)

Comment: Thank you very much! Can’t believe I’ve overlooked this.